# How to do Model validation in MVC with Web API 2?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to Web API2. My solution has 3 projects (MVC, WebAPI2, Class library for EF). I have below doubts.

1) Have kept WebAPI and MVC as separate projects for separation of concerns. Is it advisable or it is better to keep both in single project?

2) With WCF we can take service reference in MVC to avail all DB class models so that it will be easy in MVC to scaffold the controllers and to add Model validations. How to do that with Web API2 as I will not have reference in MVC for DB classes. Do I need to create duplicate DB class models in the MVC project for scaffolding purpose and model validation purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title confuses me a fair bit, but model validation can be done with validation attributes. I will try and answer the questions in the body of your question post.

It depends on how you expect to use your MVC and WebApi projects.
Keep in mind you may make things easier for yourself if they in the same project so you don't need to worry too much about RPC. But who knows how you intend to use them.

WebAPI is normally used for integration with systems other than your own. For this reason (de)serialization and request/response handling is highly customizable. The models used for the WebAPI controller are often specified or provided to the system the interface is intended to integrate with.

The model used for the WebAPI or MVC controller should be separate to the entity model for your ORM. The reason you would want to do this is that the data in your entity model does not always fit the use of the view or the validation of the view model that is sent back to the controller from the view.

In both cases the models that interface your WebAPI and MVC controllers should be designed to accommodate your use cases and should be fairly decoupled from your entity models for persistence.

So to answer your second question you probably only need one set of entity models and probably only one dbcontext implementation, but have all of that in its own project so that if you do have separate MVC and WebAPI projects they both depend on that EF project.